# How to fix responsive drop down menu using css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation, responsive-design

this is [my site](http://constantin-entertainment.info/salisburylandscaping/). the theme is customizeit which is responsive.when viewed in mobile screen.the top menu comes as a dropdown with white blocks.cannot see the text items.please help me in this without losing the responsivenes.Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each `<li>` in the responsive dropdown menu, there is a **`text-align:left`** property on the CSS selector `.tc-hover-menu.nav li` which is in the CSS file *blue.css*.

Remove the `text-align: left;` from your CSS and the text will appear. Or you can change it to `text-align: center;` and you'll see the same results.